# How to use Hub API using Curl in php

Tags: php, api, curl, laravel-5

I have purchase Hub API from RouteHappy website for search flights using Source and Destination.

They give me below code for using their API

```
curl \
  -H "Auth: YOUR_API_KEY" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.api.v3+json" \
  -G \
  -d ids=DSM-ORD-AA-3558-20160907-FIRST \
  -d include=seat,wifi \
  YOUR_HOST/segments
```

But I am not able to use Flight API using Curl in PHP, Laravel.Please help me out to access API and get desire result.

Comment: What have you tried, where is your code? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How did you write this curl request in php?

Comment: I am not aware from this. Can you please guide me how to use it in php code ?

Comment: You should probably look into using Guzzle. https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: Okay thanks but where i can pas API key

Answer (score 0):

the equivalent using [hhb_curl](https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php#L477)  would be

```
echo (new hhb_curl ( '', true ))->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_URL => 'YOUR_HOST/segments',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                "Auth: YOUR_API_KEY",
                "Accept: application/vnd.api.v3+json" 
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( array (
                'ids' => 'DSM-ORD-AA-3558-20160907-FIRST',
                'include' => 'seat,wifi' 
        ) ) 
) )->exec ()->getStdOut ();
```

- and the equivalent using [the native curl_ api](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) would be very much like that, but with a lot more manual labour (checking return types of setopt and exec, and creating a temporary output file for curl, cleaning up the resources/memory of the temp file and curl when you're finished, etc, all of which hhb_curl does for you automatically. and curl errors are converted to [RuntimeExceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php))